# python / flask: How to run a function whenever another is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, flask, binding

I have a function called `when_login()`

I need to always run it whenever `login_user()` function from `Flask-Login` module is called

- sequence :

  1. User provide credentials
  2. credentials go through auth steps

  > auth is via a mass of methods
  > 3. once user is authinticated call `login_user()`
  > 4. *[step needed]*: whenever `login_user()` is called then call a function called `when_login()` on the user logged before redirection

I'm not able to edit / rewrite `login_user()` to call `when_login()` and the program functionality

also rewriting functions could lead to slowing down the app

**Generally: is there a way of binding functions in python without editing the first that will be called?**

> This is for a flask application but I'd be pleased with python-wide answer.

Comment: just to be clear, you ALWAYS want `when_login` to run first when you ALWAYS call `login_user`?

Comment: `login_user()` runs first then automatically `when_login()` runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, there maybe a Flask specific way to do this, but here is what I have tried

```
from flask_login import login_user as login_user__

def run_first(fun):
    def inner(*args):
        fun(*args)
        when_login() # add arguments you want for making this call
    return inner

def when_login(*args):
    print('processing something with args in when_login')

@run_first
def login_user(*args):
    print('login_user is running first')
    return login_user__(*args)

login_user() # call this however you normally use
```

Output:

```
login_user is running first
processing something with args in when_login
```

Calling `login_user` makes that run first followed by `when_login`, you can notice that in the print statements.

This does not require you to change your code, add this at the top level before you start your flask process.

Comment: @Abd-ElazizSharaf if you dont find any better solutions, you can mark this as accepted

Comment: This is really helpful, only I'm waiting to see if there is another idea
Sometimes you find more than an answer for a question you couldn't solve

Comment: yes, I should have mentioned, "any better solutions later", do accept what works the best for you

Comment: decorator for this case is the fastest option in my view! But if you need more control on flask login, you could override it, but it would mean that you need to do more work. I would suggest using decorators instead!